# How to disable the_excerpt from one post

Tags: posts, the-content, excerpt

I have this code for the_excerpt :

```
function get_excerpt(){
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 640);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'<a class="read-more" <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">read more.</a>';
    return $excerpt;
}`
```

I want to disable from one post the_excerpt. I think that this part of function helps but this is not happened.

```
if( in_array( $post->ID, array(post_ID) ) ) 
    get_the_content();
else
    get_excerpt();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, WordPress already includes a function for displaying excerpts: [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt)

Secondly, your second piece of code isn't actually displaying anything. You need to use the [`echo`](http://www.php.net/echo) statement for displaying text on the page. However, WordPress provides functions that actually display the content and excerpt on the page: [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content) and [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt), respectively.

```
if( in_array( $post->ID, array(post_ID) ) ) 
    the_content();
else
    the_excerpt();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. In the second piece of code , i don't want to display anything. Actually, i want this : If the post have this post_ID, then apply the_content, else apply the_excerpt.  What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I write this part of code, inside the loop of my index.php `<?php if(in_array( $post->ID,array(333))) {
     the_content();
     } else {
     echo get_the_excerpt();}?>` and for this case has enabled the [..] of  `the_excerpt()`, and i don't want this.

Comment: Oh i have done a big mistake. In my **functions.php**, i have this code : `function get_excerpt(){
    $excerpt = get_the_content();` and in the loop of **index.php :** `echo get_the_content();
     } else {
     echo get_excerpt();}`. I replaced the variables correctly and it' works. :)

Comment: This code applied for post, how to enable for categories?